# Changing parameter values inside a loup

Tags: pyomo

I have  created a parameter to report values after each instance solve in an iterative program.I wan't my parameter to be indexed by the set that defines the number of iteration and have two other free indexes like so:

```
model.report=Param(model.iter,[],[])
```

I then wan't to create a function,that will be called into a while loop and that will create my model,solve an instance and give some values to some variables, whose names will be used as indexes in my report parameter, like so:

```
report(model.iter,'cost',model.i)=model.cost[i]
```

Where model.cost is my cost variable indexed by set i.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are better off simply making `model.report` a Python `dict`. Then you can assign it entries with whatever keys you like:

```
model.report = dict()
...
for j in range(10):
    # assumes model.i is a simple built-in type and not a Param
    # (otherwise you would need to use model.i.value)
    model.report[j,'cost',model.i] = model.cost[j]
```

There is no reason to use a `Param` in this context unless you are using those values in some kind of expression and you want to be able to update the expression at a later time by changing the value of the `Param` (i.e., you would use `mutable=True` when you declare the `Param`).